# 403 Access denied to specified url in Tomcat 7.0.52

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat7

I have recently migrated the tomcat server from `7.0.49` to `7.0.52`. In tomcat it contains 2 web apps which was working earlier, after migrating to this version I am facing  **403 Access denied to specified url**.

On this whenever we try it out for first time on a browser or a tab facing the 403 error but when we refresh the page, it is redirecting to login page.

One more thing I would like to add here is only one application is resulting with this 403 error. So I tried to compare with Tomcat config files on both versions and verified there is no change exception version specific changes.

Adding more debugging points on this issue, On **web.xml** there the role is been defined, so tried Commenting it out. it's getting redirected to Login Page.

Can any one please share ideas on this issues.

Comment: How are you deploying the apps. Do you just put the applications in webapps directory or you have some specific configuration for them in server.xml file or other (context) files ?

Comment: To be more specific both applications are deployed as an image along with tomcat into the webapps .So it is being handled based on the  services.

Comment: Are you having this each time you restart the server?

Comment: Yes it happens on every time , whenever access the host.

Comment: Just another idea: Do you use lastest version of java 7? What vendor: openjdk or sun jdk? There was some bugs in openjdk regarding httpurlconnection which could affect applications running on Tomcat using this version. If you use java 6 or java 7 (which is not lastest version), try also with updated version of jdk 7. See for example here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8012625

Comment: Yes am using **JVM Version:    1.7.0_76-b13** ,  In very build also the tomcat is using the same java version only , but there was no issues with that i think so.

Answer (score 4):

Try clearing browser cache before doing first request. Maybe application which gives 403 uses some authoriztion cookie (like sso cookie or possibbly jsessionid). This cookie can be significant. If this is the case than after clearing cookies you should be directed to login page directly.

This would explain why one application works and another not (some state on client browser can be held)

Comment: Yep i have tried even though am facing same issues.Thanks for sharing your ideas..

Comment: qualified deep-known answer, why so cheap reputation?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the strategy how sessions are passivated has been changed between 7.0.49 and 7.0.52.

Try to delete all passivated sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problems in the past when I started to use same Tomcat version.

If I recall correctly, there was some misconception between Tomcat and Servlet spec leading to some servlets starting twice. You can read a little more [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html#Annotation_scanning).

Anyway, what I always worked for me is add `metadata-complete="true"` in `web-app` element in `web.xml`. This is a pity, in my opinion, as I use Java only configuration, and I must keep this file only for this.